Snapshots are too big and constantly fills my SSD!
I keep getting out of space warnings, and the only way to reclaim that is using Daisy Disk. Disk Utility always shows "resource busy". Some thoughts:

perhaps it's possible to decrease the "High Tide Mark" and avoid the creation of a snapshot that goes beyond it?
each snapshot is crazy big, I saw some snapshots screenshot images on the net and they are much smaller than mine, so question is: How do I find which files are getting changed so often? I think it may be iCloud Drive, perhaps? Either way this is not working the right way!
I turned off Backblaze, and other stuff that goes into "hidden" but I got bitten again today;
Just to remember, I bought a 1TB SSD, and I have 2TB in iCloud, I'd like to keep using them as advertised! ;c)
Lastly, this madness started after Sonoma 14.4.

Some images below. The first one where I just "freed 400GB" and right after I refreshed it and I have zero again!




For looking to see what is in a Time Machine Backup I use BackupLoupe but I am not certain if that works on local snapshots, I use a desktop

I used Backup Loupe like @mmmmmm suggested, and I see no backups that are close to the size of the snapshots above, the largest ones hover around 40GB. So I guess there's no relation between snapshot size and backup size, and it's not something causing big snapshots by changing a lot of files at the same time as I initially thought.

@mmmmmm BackupLoupe measures snapshots on the TM destination. It does not look at the source disk.

In Disk Utility show the "Private Size" column - that is the size of files unique to a snapshot.  The "Size" column is the cumulative size of a snapshot plus all the older snapshots. Your 237GB in DU is same as 237GB in DD - the size of all snapshots.  Also when you delete files, they will remain in snapshots until TM purges them 24 hours later (you should turn on automatic hourly backups) - this what you are seeing when deleting 400GB as much that will be still on disk in snapshots.  Also, DD is showing 392GB as purgeable - this will be released if macOS needs the space.

@Gilby about "this will be released if macOS needs the space", this is the whole problem, it doesnt. I have to force it to be released or I get a lot of "no space left on device" errors! :c(  ☞ turning on hourly backups, but I was that way before and I kept getting spece errors. let's hope I get a different milage this time.

This may be related with previous question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/467393/missing-free-space-after-sonoma-and-its-not-snapshots/467413?noredirect=1#comment705933_467413
